# How does kubernetes Operator inject or update environment variables into containers

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-operator

I have a project that needs to **inject or update environment variables** in the pod container, using `kubebuilder` and `controller-runtime`,

My plan is as follows:

```
func Reconcile(){
    // get added environment variables
    // get matched pods
    // update container env
}
```

After I tried to update, the following error occurred

```
 "namespace": "default", "error": "Pod \"busybox\" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)\n  core.PodSpec{\n  \tVolumes:        []core.Volume{{Name: \"default-token-bcr86\", VolumeSource: core.VolumeSource{Secret: &core.SecretVolumeSource{SecretName: \"default-token-bcr86\", DefaultMode: &420}}}},\n  \tInitContainers: nil,\n  \tContainers: []core.Container{\n  \t\t{\n  \t\t\t... // 5 identical fields\n  \t\t\tPorts:        nil,\n  \t\t\tEnvFrom:      nil,\n- \t\t\tEnv:          []core.EnvVar{
```

```
# pod.yml of busybox
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
  labels:
    match: "test"
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: busybox
  restartPolicy: Always
```

but it seems that env cannot be updated in the source code

`//  k8s.io/api/core/v1/types.go`

```
// A single application container that you want to run within a pod.
type Container struct {
    .....
    // List of sources to populate environment variables in the container.
    // The keys defined within a source must be a C_IDENTIFIER. All invalid keys
    // will be reported as an event when the container is starting. When a key exists in multiple
    // sources, the value associated with the last source will take precedence.
    // Values defined by an Env with a duplicate key will take precedence.
    // Cannot be updated.
    // +optional
    EnvFrom []EnvFromSource `json:"envFrom,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,19,rep,name=envFrom"`
    // List of environment variables to set in the container.
    // Cannot be updated.
    // +optional
    // +patchMergeKey=name
    // +patchStrategy=merge
    Env []EnvVar `json:"env,omitempty" patchStrategy:"merge" patchMergeKey:"name" protobuf:"bytes,7,rep,name=env"`
    .....
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.

Comment: could you please share the busybox pod deployment yaml file?

Comment: @Bazhikov I've added that

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this on a running pod without killing the pod and restarting it with a new config (containing your updated env vars) because these are set at pod startup.

Some options:

1. Kill the pod and recreate it with the new env vars.
2. Update the env vars in the deployment instead of the pod which will rollout the change.
3. Consider using some other means of storing these key-value pairs (ex: a volume, or a Custom Resource).

Can you describe your use case a bit more?